# broom, regressions for subgroups: How to deal with error in reg a subgrup?

Tags: r, dplyr, broom

I am using `dplyr` + the `broom` package to run separate regression for each subgroup in my

```
my_data %>% group_by(my_groups) %>% 
    do(tidy(lm( attended_school ~ treated + I_post_treatmet, data=.) 
            ))
```

(the actuall data is of restricted access, can't share here)

I get the following error:

```
Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases
```

If I understood correctly this means the regression could not be run for some subgroup, possibly due to all NAs in some variable.

How can I catch those errors so that in the end I receive a dataset containing the regression outputs for the subgroups in which the regressions ran sucessfully?

EDIT: tryed a syntax similar to the link suggested in the comments and got the same problem:

```
my_data %>% group_by(my_groups) %>% 
    do(aa=tryCatch(lm( attended_school ~ treated + I_post_treatmet, data=.) 
            ))
```

Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) : 
  0 (non-NA) cases

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39044500/comparing-models-with-dplyr-and-broomglance-how-to-continue-if-error-is-produ) looks closely related

Comment: I tryed that and several close variations. Nothing worked

Comment: Did you try the exact solution in the answer in the link?  You haven't included an reproducible example so no one else can test if that answer works in your situation or not.

Comment: You didn't include the second argument to `tryCatch` from that link, which is the relevant one.